# How to scrape data from multiple pages using Scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape data from multiple pages using Scrapy. I'musing the code below, what am I doing wrong?

```
import scrapy 
class CollegeSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'college'
    allowed_domains = ['https://engineering.careers360.com/colleges/list-of-engineering-colleges-in-India?sort_filter=alpha']
    start_urls = ['https://engineering.careers360.com/colleges/list-of-engineering-colleges-in-India?sort_filter=alpha/']
    def parse(self,response):
        for college in response.css('div.title'):
            if college.css('a::text').extract_first():
                yield {'college_name':college.css('a::text').extract_first()}
    next_page_url=response.css('li.page-next>a::attr(href)').extract_first()
    next_page_url=response.urljoin(next_page_url)
    yield scrapy.Request(url=next_page_url,callback=self.praise)
```

Comment: You should explain your question in the body of the form and not only in the title.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think you are doing something wrong? Does it show any error? If so, the output should be included in the question in the first place. If it's not doing what you expected, again, you should tell us.

Anyway, looking at the code, there are at least two possible errors:

- `allowed_domains` should be just a domain name, not full URL, as [documented](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Spider.allowed_domains).
- when you yield new `Request` to the next page, you should give `callback=self.parse` instead of `self.praise` to process the response the same way as the first URL

Comment: Thank You for rectifying my errors.Sir, I altered my code as per your direction but only two requests are generated for this code.